# Find polymorphic association for destroy action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

So I have a polymorphic favorite model that allows users to favorite all kinds of different things (and currently works ok methinks). I'm now trying to destroy their favorites but having difficulties selecting the favorite to destroy, I don't know how to start the form_for.

My create looks like this:

units_controller.rb - here I create the @favorite for the form_for

```
  @favorite = Favorite.new 
  @favorable = @unit
```

_favorite.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@user, @favorable, @favorite]) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.hidden_field :favorer %></div>
  <%= f.submit "Favorite", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

favorites_controller.rb

```
  def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @favorite = @favorable.favorites.new(params[:favorite])
    @favorite.favorer = current_user
    @favorite.save  # Favorite id: 1, favorer: 2, favorable_id: 1, favorable_type: "Unit"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to :back }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

Here's what I've got so far on delete but I'm unsure how to call the form_for:

_unfavorite.html.erb

```
<%= form_for([@user, @favorable, @favorite], # problems here as @favorite is Favorite.new
             html: { method: :delete }, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "Unfavorite", class: "btn btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

favorites_controller.rb

```
def destroy
  @favorite = Favorite.find(params[:id])
  @favorite.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @user }
    format.js
  end
end
```

My follow model uses this, but I'm not sure how to nest it under /users/1/units/1/favorites

```
current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@user)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out...

```
def destroy
  @user = current_user
  @favorite = @favorable.favorites.where(favorer: current_user).first
  @favorite.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a bug in your `_unfavorite.html.erb` markup? It seems like it's missing a comma.
I'm working on something similar and am having problems deleting a polymorphic photo.

Comment: eh, yes there is. Looks like I botched copying. I will edit it to correct it.

Comment: I also used these two for a lot of the code http://www.doblock.com/articles/creating-an-extensible-user-favorites-system-in-rails (for polymorphic) and https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed (javascript delete pulled from following model)